# Form validation HTML & JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the form validation .

```
       <form id="my_form">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class=" col-md-5 " >
            <label  for="name"> ORDER *  </label>
            <input id="Auftrag"  name="Auftrag" type="text" class="form-control" >
..............................
..............................
:...........................
..................................
```

And JQUERY CODE IS:

```
   $(function ()
   {
   $.validator.addMethod('Auftragcheck', function(value,element)
    {
        return value.length==8
        && /\d/.test(value)  
        && /[a-z]/i. test(value);
    }, 'Order number should contain first letter N and 7 numbers.') 
  $("#my_form").validate (
  {
    rules:
    {
        email: {
            required: true, 
            email : true
        },

        Auftrag: {
            required: true,
            Auftragcheck: true
        }
    },
    messages: //if the entry is not filled correctly
    {
        email: {

        email: 'Please enter VALID email address',
        required: 'Please enter email address'
            }
    }
});
```

});

This is working good But I want to Check the array . That if first digit is not "N", then it should display the error. How to do that in the form of array ?
I have to use only Javascript/JQUERY. I know it can be done by PHP but i am not supposed to do PHP.

What can be the solution:

Thank you

Comment: Which array are you talking about? All you need to do is change the regular expression:  `/^N[a-z]{7}$/i` (this already includes a total length of 8)

Comment: note by the way that client-side validation doesn't mean we shouldn't validate on the server , honestly client-side validation is just to respond errors quicker to the user

Comment: Yes . this expression is actually donot understand.. i tried to figure it out what does it actually mean..  i will try it in my code . can you please share a link for such expression so that i can read about that in detail.
Thank you 

and i am more curious to know about such expressions for JQUERY . so that i can customised it according to my needs.

Comment: it's called regex(shorthand for regular-expressions), see here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

Comment: Yes Thank you. it helped !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code with First Letter "N" and seven numbers

```js
$(function ()
   {
   $.validator.addMethod('Auftragcheck', function(value,element)
    {
        return value.length==8
        && /^N[0-9]{7}$/i.test(value);
    }, 'Order number should contain first letter N and 7 numbers.') 
  $("#my_form").validate (
  {
    rules:
    {

        Auftrag: {
            required: true,
            Auftragcheck: true
        }
    },
    messages: //if the entry is not filled correctly
    {
        email: {

        email: 'Please enter VALID email address',
        required: 'Please enter email address'
            }
    }
});
});
```

```html
<form id="my_form">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class=" col-md-5 " >
            <label  for="name"> ORDER *  </label>
            <input id="Auftrag"  name="Auftrag" type="text" class="form-control" max-length="8">
            <div class=col-md-6>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="form-control" >            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
```